# document.querySelector() combine class names and attribute both

Tags: javascript, css, queryselector

How can I combine both class names and element attributes in a document.querySelector() call.

let's say my element is as below:

```
<div role="button" class="fj2rt Gdrwg"></div>
```

I want to pass both class names and attribute in the document.querySelector() call
for example:

```
let btn = document.querySelector('.fj2rt.Gdrwg [role="button"]';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No space needed between the role name and class name.

So `document.querySelector('.fj2rt.Gdrwg [role="button"]';` should be replaced with `document.querySelector('.fj2rt.Gdrwg[role="button"]';`.

I have attached working example.

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('.fj2rt.Gdrwg[role="button"]');
console.log(btn);
```

```html
<div role="button" class="fj2rt Gdrwg"></div>
```

Comment: Can you pls approve my question if it works well on you?

Comment: have to wait another 3 mins to do that according to stackoverflow :)